# Why doesn't the C++ standard library have a version of deque with contiguous memory?

Tags: c++, c++11, data-structures, stl

From what I understand, deque allocates new constant sized blocks of memory as you need them, without any guarantee that they will be contiguous. This makes sure that removing from either side will not invalidate any iterators that are currently pointing at the deque.

This memory layout is handy for certain situations, but its generally slower than storing memory contiguously.

The go-to container for speedier contiguous memory is the vector, but it doesn't allow you to push or pop from the front.

I don't understand why that is.

I'm sure that it's possible to implement a deque that uses contiguous memory, and it seems like it would be strictly superior to a vector. Its memory layout would be equally as fast and it would also allow efficient pushing/popping from the front.

Not only that, but I feel like it would also make more sense from a design perspective. The contiguous deque would be the go-to for it's speed, and the non-contiguous deque would be used when it's memory layout fits the problem at hand better.

If I'm missing something or being incredibly short sighted please let me know. Why isn't there a contiguous deque in the standard library?

Comment: So if you push to the front in your novel container, what happens to all the elements after it?

Comment: @TartanLlama: nothing happens to them when you use a ring buffer.

Comment: @YvesDaoust A ring buffer is not contiguous.

Comment: @gha.st: since when ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust Since it wraps, and thus uses two areas of memory?

Comment: @gha.st: it is a single, contiguous area.

Comment: Use a `std::vector`.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Depends on your definition. But you *can* send the entire contents of a `vector<T>` into a function expecting a `T*`. That's not possible with a ring buffer.

Comment: I can't believe the *non-contiguous* votes for ring buffer are winning... Its a contiguous block and the wrapping happens in software.

Comment: Since you're "sure it's possible to implement" such a data structure, perhaps you should outline *how* that would be done? We could then evaluate that idea.

Comment: @Galik OK, how do you send a ring buffer to [`glTexImage1D`](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/docbook4/xhtml/glTexImage1D.xml) or [`saxpy`](http://www.mathkeisan.com/usersguide/man/saxpy.html)?

Comment: Well it's a contiguous area, but the elements are not necessarily stored adjacent in memory.

Comment: *"I'm sure that it's possible to implement a deque that uses contiguous memory"* - this can be *trivially* layered atop a `std::vector` - then you can also tune the resizing behaviour - so what's the problem?  If there's developer time available Standard Library enhancement, I for one would rather see the effort put into things that are non-trivial for users to currently do, such as a closed hashing aka open addressing hash table (with values stored directly in buckets), a trie or graph - they're things the average developer would find tricky to do well.

Comment: In this post, contiguous is understood with respect to memory allocation, i.e. single block.

Comment: @galik all memory is contiguous, if you ignore the gaps, on flat memory systems.

Comment: @TonyD What i'm wondering is, if it's trivial to do and would result in a structure that's superior to vector, why not do it?

Comment: @djscrew: lack of demand / evidence that it's frequently significantly beneficial, the people who do want this enough to implement it would settle for a common implementation, and nobody bothering to propose it.  You can write an implementation and propose it yourself you know, or even propose it for boost and if it's popular and robust there, the Standard sometime later.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The containers on the Standard Library are not meant to cover every possible use case, they are just a selection of useful data structures with (mostly) non-overlapping properties (if you count the four associative containers as a single family, and the four unordered containers as another family).

For contiguous memory, use vector. For efficient splicing, use list. For efficient insertions and removals at either end **without lots of reallocation and shuffling**, use deque etc.

If you want a different data structure then write it, that's the point of the STL design: any other container that follows the same principles will work perfectly with STL-style algorithms.

The structure you propose would have more overhead than vector, requiring four pointers not three. It would probably need front-capacity and back-capacity member functions, so you could know whether inserting at either end would reallocate and/or invalidate iterators. When it runs out of space at one end you would have to decide whether to reallocate or just shuffle everything along into the free space at the other end. Depending on the usage patterns making the wrong decision could be expensive (e.g. it might be better just to reallocate and have more room to grow at both ends, but that could lead to lots of wasted space at one end, and if you shuffle instead of reallocating you might just be delaying the inevitable and have to reallocate later anyway).

But these are not unsolvable problems so in principle nothing prevents you writing such a container. That doesn't mean it necessarily needs to be in the Standard Library though.

The Standard Library also doesn't have containers like Boost.Container's flat_map and stable_vector, but you can find them in third-party libraries instead. Again, that extensibility is the whole point of the STL design.

Answer (score 5):

It already exists. You can insert at the front of a vector.

Yes, sure, it invalidates references and iterators and requires the contents of the vector to be copied (or moved), but that's the tradeoff you have to make if you want contiguous memory.

What a deque gives you is the guarantee that inserting at either end will *not* invalidate references to existing elements. And that is only possible because it *doesn't* use contiguous memory.

Comment: I know that you can push to the front of a vector, but I'm pretty sure it can be done without shifting all the elements after it over. You would have a front and back index, and when you push to the front, the front index decrements, wrapping around the the end of the allocated memory. That way you wouldn't have to shift the objects around.

Comment: @djscrew, that requires you to decide the maximum number of elements in advance, and to preallocate all the memory.

Comment: Not necessarily. Once the block of memory you have is filled up, you can rewrite all of it to a larger block of memory. Growing would work the same as a vector, but it would preserve the ability to efficiently push and pop from the front

Comment: @djscrew: Implement it, put it on GitHub, submit it to the Boost Library Incubator.

Comment: @Blastfurnace Not a bad idea, that'd force me to learn exception safety.

Comment: @djscrew: In the outline above where the arena grows on demand, you end up with a container on which iterators are invalidated on insert (not all inserts, but those that grow the buffer), this is the main advantage of deque. If you only want to avoid the potential deficiency in segmented allocation (which in the case of VS comes close to a list), then it is trivially implementable on top of vector. I don't consider that to be a general purpose container and doubt that it should be in the standard library.

Comment: @djscrew: And by all means: do implement a (any) container, make it exception safe (choose the level of safety vs. performance, test different balances...) it is a great learning exercise.

Comment: @djscrew sure, but then it's nothing like a deque, because the guarantee a deque gives is that references stay valid or *all* inserts made to the front or back. Your proposal would only work up to some pre-reserved limit. I'm not saying what you're proposing couldn't work or be useful (and could probably be made as a fairly simple adaptor class around a vector), but it wouldn't be anything like a deque.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose, there is little need for such a container, as the penalty for contiguous memory will be the invalidation of iterators and re-allocation (including copying/moving of elements) if you push beyond the allocated memory.

`deque` supports pushing on either end at O(1) costs *without* invalidating existing iterators, re-allocation, copying, or moving of elements. This has apparently been deemed more important than contiguous memory.

A `vector` implements a growable container of contiguous memory and is implemented via three data members, corresponding to `begin`, `end`, and `end_memory`:

```
P-------------E----------C   linear memory
^             ^          ^
begin         end        end_memory
```

So as long as `end<end_memory` you can `push_back` (=`++end`) and you can always `pop_back` (=`--end`). Initially, `end=end_memory=begin+size`, so that if you never push or pop, no memory is wasted and no re-allocations are required (if you `reserve()`, then `end_memory=begin+capacity` allows you to do some `push_back`s without re-allocation).

In order have contiguous memory and also be able to efficiently `push_front`, you would need four data members:

```
A------------B--------E---------C   // linear memory
^            ^        ^         ^
begin_memory begin    end       end_memory
```

when `push_front` is implemented as `--begin`. However, there is no obvious way for what `begin` shall be when constructing a new container. You could use the defaults `begin_memory=begin` and `end=end_memory=begin+size`, but you would have a more complicated `reserve`:

```
reserve(size_t capacity_to_push_front,
        size_t capacity_to_push_back);
```

Thus, if you really need that, go ahead and implement it yourself.

Comment: So essentially the higher complexity outweighs the usefulness of pushing/popping from the front. Thanks, thats the answer I was looking for.